# What transaction logs are for

Tags: sql-server-2005, backup, transaction-log, rollback

I'm confused about tranasaction logs for SQL Server. I was under the impression they can be used to roll the database forward. For example say I made a software release on Sunday, I added three new columns. But four days down the line we discover a bug, could I roll the database back to the Sunday's backup before I did the release and then use the transaction logs to insert any data that's been inserted since Sunday?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do what you're asking.  You should have your database in full recovery mode and then be performing log backups (via jobs/maintenance plans).

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190982(v=sql.90).aspx